# dhtmlxScheduler using ASP.NET MVC Refresh Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx

I am getting an error about incorrect html when I return from the Save view which means the displayed scheduler is not being refreshed to fix the last set of data. Having made a change or addition, it is displayed correctly if I close the website and open it again, so the update has been saved in the table. It is just the refreshing of the currennt view that I am having problems with. Does anybody have any suggestions as to where I might look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, this was my mistake. I had created a new project and copied the Save.aspx view from another project. The `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<RLSBCWebSite.Controllers.CalendarActionResponseModel>"` still referred to the old project.

Make sure you create a new page in your project and copy just the contenets from old projects!